# Quadratic forms and midpoints

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The midpoint of the vectors $u$ and $v$ is $w=\frac{u+v}{2}$. In euclidean geometry, an alternative characteristic of midpoints is $|v-w|=|u-w|=\frac{1}{2}|u-v|$.

I wonder if this generalizes to (possibly nondegenerate) quadratic forms $Q=Q(v)$ acting on $
R^{N}$. That is, $w=\frac{u+v}{2}$ exactly when
$$Q(u-w)=Q(v-w)=\frac{1}{4}Q(u-v).$$

Comment: Hint: Easier to check $Q(d)=Q(-d)=Q(2d)/4$, which immediately implies that the quadratic form must be homogeneous.

Comment: @Yves, isn't "homogeneous" part of the definition of "form"?

Comment: @Gerry: oooops, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruler postulate:

Given a line $L$ through points $u$ and $v$ in Eucliean space, there always exists a coordinate system and a function $f:\mathbb R \to L$ such that

1. $f(0) = u$,
2. $f(1) = v$, and,
3. For any two points $a, b \in \mathbf L,\quad d(f(a), \, f(b)) = |a - b|$.

That function is actually pretty easy to construct.

$f(\lambda) = (1-\lambda)u + \lambda v$.

Note that $f(0) = u$ and $f(1) = v$. If you wanted, for example, to trisect the segment $\overline{ab}$, You would compute the sequence of points
$f(0), f(\frac 13), f(\frac 23), f(1) = 
u, \frac 23u + \frac 13v, \frac 13u + \frac 23v, v$

Comment: Is there any relationship between $u$ and $v$ defining the line, and $A$ and $B$ being the function $f$ parameters?

Comment: @CiaPan I have a dyslexic-type problem where I often type things in a different order than I am thinking them. I made some major corrections to what I originally wrote. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you. (To strict rules watchmen: Yes, I know 'thankyous' are discouraged here. But that was an actual improvement, not just a typo correction, and made on my suggestion. so I am pretty sure it deserves appreciation and thanks.)